# meera font in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, unicode, fonts

I am using unicode font meera which is used for malayalam ,that is a local language in india in my website. And large posts showing some big fonts in Chrome. But it works perfectly in all other browsers. Here I am providing screeshots of the contents in firefox and chrome.

[image]

can somebody help me please?.

Comment: Please show the code you are using, preferably together with the URL of your page (because font issues often relate to how servers send font files).

Comment: http://bjm.kemoztechnologies.com/irp_book_detail.php?id=65&title=%E0%B4%AC%E0%B4%A8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%A7%E0%B4%99%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%99%E0%B4%B3%E0%B5%82%E0%B4%9F%E0%B5%86%20%E0%B4%AE%E0%B4%A8%E0%B4%B6%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%B8%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%A4%E0%B5%8D%E0%B4%B0%E0%B4%82%20(%E0%B4%AD%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%97%E0%B4%82-1)

Comment: this is the url for my site,please give me a solution to tackle this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with encoding format of Google Chrome.
The following solution worked for me.

- Google Chrome Settings -> Show advanced settings...
- Web content Section -> Customize Fonts ...
- Select Encoding Unicode (UTF-8). Click Done.
- Restart Chrome.

Enjoy !!!